# On a cosine inequality on a sphere

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Task : There (probably) exists a constant $C\in (0,1)$ and $a \in (-1,1)$ independent of everything that follows such that, for all $R>1$, $\frac 1R < r < 1$, we have $$
\mathbb P_{h \in U(S_r)}\left(\cos(Rh_1) \leq a\right) \geq C
$$
where $U(S_r)$ is the uniform measure on the sphere of radius $r$ given by $|h| = r$.

---

This question arises while computing a lower bound for a Fourier coefficient. While I would like people to answer the original question, for contextual purposes I will mention the origin of this question.

The original question that arose was to look for the existence of a universal constant $C>0$ such that for every vector $u \in \mathbb R^d$, $$
|u| > 1 \implies \int_{|h|<1} \frac{(1-\cos(u \cdot h))}{|h|^d}dh \geq C \log |u|
$$

This arose from the tightness of the reverse inequality : writing $1-\cos(u \cdot h) \leq 2$ and integrating $\frac{1}{|h|^d}$ only over the region $\frac{1}{|u|} < |h| < 1$ yields the reverse bound $2C \log |u|$. Over the region $|h|<\frac{1}{|u|}$, writing $(1-\cos(u \cdot h)) \approx \frac{(u \cdot h)^2}2$ by the Taylor expansion of the cosine, using Cauchy-Schwarz and then integrating ensures that this particular integral is bounded by a constant (independent of $u$). Hence, the reverse bound is roughly of order $\log |u|$.

To get to my question,first we do $$
\int_{|h|<1} \frac{(1-\cos(u \cdot h))}{|h|^d}dh \geq \int_{\frac 1{|u|} < |h|<1} \frac{(1-\cos(u \cdot h))}{|h|^d}dh
$$
Now, we WLOG assume that $u=Re_1$ where $R = |u|$ and $e_1$ is the first standard basis vector. Then $u \cdot h = Rh_1$. This is not a problem since the integral in question is rotation invariant. Now, we do $$
\int_{\frac 1{|u|} < |h|<1} \frac{(1-\cos(Rh_1))}{|h|^d}dh \geq (1-a)\int_{\frac{1}{|u|}<|h|<1 : \cos(Rh_1) \leq a} \frac{dh}{|h|^d}
$$
Converting to radial coordinates via Fubini's theorem, $$
(1-a)\int_{\frac{1}{|u|}<|h|<1 : \cos(Rh_1) \leq a} \frac{dh}{|h|^d} \geq (1-a)\int_{\frac{1}{|u|}}^{1}\frac{dr}{r^{d}} |\{|h| = r : \cos(Rh_1) \leq a\}| \\= C(1-a)\int_{\frac {1}{|u|}}^1 \frac {dr}{r} \mathbb P_{h \in U(S_r)}\left(\cos(Rh_1) \leq a\right)
$$
by multiplying and dividing by the volume of $\{|h|=r\}$ which equals $Cr^{d-1}$ for some fixed constant $C$. Now, if the "task" is true, then the probability part comes out as a constant, leading to $\int_{\frac {1}{|u|}}^1 \frac {dr}{r}$ giving me what I need.